# exporting module in node.js and nw.js but unable to call to constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, nw.js

I am creating web application using node.js and nw.js
Now i am exporting the below module

> admin.js

```
module.exports = function (firstName, lastName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.fullName = function () { 
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}}
```

> and trying to access it in login.js file

```
var adm= require('./model/admin.js');
var adms=new adm("hi","wow");    
adms.fullName();
```

> But it says adm is not a constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems great.

Try maybe to change your admin.js but usualy your code should work

```
var adm = function (firstName, lastName) {
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
   this.fullName = function () {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
   }
}
var exports = module.exports = adm
```